# Cross product parallelpiped question

Tags: vectors, volume

Hey guys can you help me with a question?

So far I've got, $$P_1 = \frac{1}{{P_2}^3} (\textbf{u}\times \textbf{v})\cdot((\textbf{v}\times \textbf{w})\times(\textbf{w}\times \textbf{u}))$$

[image]

Comment: \cdot is a better way to write the dot product, and I'm assuming you've already done part a). For part b it would help to use some vector product identities like $(a\times b) \times (c \times d) = (a\cdot (b\times d))c - (a \cdot ( b \times c)) d$

Comment: Maybe the last formula of the section "Addition and multiplication" (or some others of that list) can be useful to simplify your expression further
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_calculus_identities#Addition_and_multiplication